# How to locate .jrxml file in java?

Tags: java, jasper-reports

What I'm trying to do is to create a simple report in jasper iReport and view it in Javafx file.

When I try to open the file it throws a error at this line:

```
JasperDesign jasperdesign = JRXmlLoader.load("C:\\Users\\chirag\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\User_management_application\\src\\reports\\UserLogs.jrxml");
```

The report path is copied from the properties of `UserLogs.jrxml` file

The method snippet where I am trying to load the report:

```
   try {
                JasperReport jasperReport;
                JasperPrint jasperPrint;
                String qry = "SELECT * FROM user_master a inner join user_log_management b on a.User_Master_Id = b.userMaster_User_Master_Id where b.Entry_Date like '" + date1.getValue() + "%'";
                JRDesignQuery newQuer = new JRDesignQuery();
                newQuer.setText(qry);
                JasperDesign jasperdesign = JRXmlLoader.load("C:\\Users\\chirag\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\User_management_application\\src\\reports\\UserLogs.jrxml");
                jasperdesign.setQuery(newQuer);
                jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(jasperdesign);
                jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, null, MySqlConnection.conn());
                boolean isLinuxSelected = radiopdf.isSelected();
                if (isLinuxSelected) {
                    JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(jasperPrint, "reports//UserLogs.pdf");
                    String pdflocation = "reports//UserLogs.pdf";
                    try {
                        if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported()) {
                            try {
                                File myFile = new File(pdflocation);
                                Desktop.getDesktop().open(myFile);    
                            } catch (Exception ex) {
                            }
                        }
                    } catch (Exception ep) {
                        Alert alerts = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.ERROR);
                        alerts.setContentText("Sorry no Records to be previewed.");
                        alerts.show();
                    }
                }  else {
                    JDialog jviewer = new JDialog();
                    JRViewer aViewer = new JRViewer(jasperPrint);
                    jviewer.setTitle("Report Preview");
                    jviewer.setModal(true);
                    jviewer.getContentPane().add(aViewer);
                    jviewer.pack();
                    java.awt.Dimension diadim = java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
                    jviewer.setSize(diadim.width, diadim.height);
                    jviewer.requestFocus();
                    jviewer.show();
                    jviewer.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
                }
                MySqlConnection.closeConnection();
                System.gc();
            } catch (JRException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(ReportsController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
```

The error message:

```
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:71)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor2.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1765)
    ... 50 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/digester/Digester
    at ControllerPack.ReportsController.generate(ReportsController.java:126)
    ... 60 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.digester.Digester
```

I am unable to figure out the error please help me.

Comment: Simply pasting your method code can't tell us which is the actual problem. Please, also put the stack-trace of the error into your post, so we can identify it if you can't.

Comment: i have updated the post with the error message i am getting.. thank you

Comment: The error is indicating that the cause of error is at line 126 in ReportsController.java. Which code is at that line?

Comment: `JasperDesign jasperdesign = JRXmlLoader.load("C:\\Users\\chirag\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\User_management_application\\src\\reports\\UserLogs.jrxml");`

Answer (score 1):

The base cause is

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.digester.Digester
```

Thus, it looks like you don't provide the required dependencies for JasperReports. Add `commons-digester-*.jar` in the version required by your JR version (and probably other missing libraries).